# Tableau, how to make a new column based on different column

Tags: tableau-desktop

### I have a big table in Tableau

### client | year | calc_percentage|

### a    |2020    | 90

### b    |2021    | 90

### c    |2022    | 90

### d    |2023    | 90

### y    |2024    | 90

### I want to make new column, it should update dynamically.
so my calc_per has two column already been calculated.

### client | year | calc_percentage| new column

### a    |2020    | 90            |  100%

### b    |2021    | 87            |  100%

### c    |2022    | 86.3          | 90

### d    |2023    | 90.45         | 87

### y    |2024    | 75.35         |90.45

I have try
IF YEAR([Date]) >= 2020 AND YEAR([Date]) <= 2021 THEN
1
ELSEIF YEAR([Date]) == 2027 THEN

```
  calc_percentage
```

else 0
END

### it gave me
client | year | calc_percentage| new column

### a    |2020    | 90            |  100%

### b    |2021    | 87            |  100%

### c    |2022    | 86.3          | 86.3

### d    |2023    | 90.45         | 90.45

### y    |2024    | 75.35         |75.35

### but I want value from 2020, I try used data blending,
it says that aggregate is not working with non aggregate

### I try to store each column, it gave me null

I try index and shift it, but it shifts by row not by year, when I add more column. I still don't get result.
How do you guys use it in Tableau?
is there a way make it dynamically? Is it even possible?
in excel I would use look up, but due to year filter I can't use it calculate field.

Any help would be helpful.
Thank you

Comment: "I want to make new column, it should update dynamically. so my calc_per has two column already been calculated." -Can you clarify this further?